# Name a variable after a variable. (looping through AD forests and counting servers and generating report)

Tags: variables, powershell, active-directory, foreach

I am counting servers in three different forests and I'd like to email the results.
I have an integer ($i) that increases for each server, but I reset this number for every forest.

Is there a way that I can create a variable from the forest name ($forest) and a $i count?
I would also love if my mail would foreach the servers in forests count so this would be dynamic.

I guess I am asking if I can name a variable after a variable.. For example $forest.$i or similar...

Please help!
And happy new year!!

Edit:

```
# Get password (this is secure!)
$password = Read-Host "Enter password" -AsSecureString

# Create a container for your objects.
$forestContainer = @()

$forests = "corp.foresta.com","corp.forestb.com","corp.forestc.com"
foreach ($forest in $forests) {

# Create credentials for forest
$credentials = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "$forest\administrator",$password

# Connect to current forest
$forestconnection = Connect-QADService -Service $forest -Credential $credentials

$servers = Get-QADComputer -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -OSName *server*,*hyper*
echo $($servers.Length)

$currentForest = New-Object PsObject -Property @{
        Name = $forest
        Count = $($servers.Length)
}
$forestContainer += $currentForest
```

}

Comment: FYI - you don't have to use a sub expression when accessing the Length property of the `$servers` array when setting the property. You can just use `$servers.Length`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about creating a custom object. Creating your own object is a great way to associate pieces of data together. In your case you'd like to associate a number to either a name of a forest or a forest object created by something else. Regardless if you are working with a list of forest name strings or objects you can use this approach.

Create a container (an array) for your custom objects.

```
$forestContainer = @()
```

As you loop through your forests, create a custom object for each and add it to the array. In this example `$myForests` is either a collection of objects or a string array of names.

```
$i = 1
foreach ($forest in $myForests) {
    # Create a custom object associating all the data you want.
    $currentForest = New-Object PsObject -Property @{
            Forest = $forest
            Count = $i
            # Note: You can add as many properties to the object here as you like.
    }
    $forestContainer += $currentForest
    $i += 1
}
```

The benefit of this approach is you will be able to use the array filled with your new objects with other Powershell cmdlets easily. For example:

```
$forestContainer | where {$_.Count -lt 2}
```

Or

```
$forestContainer | format-table
```

Or

```
$forestContainer | Out-GridView
```

To access the Count property which contains the current integer when that forest was processed you can use this syntax:

```
$forestContainer[0].Count
```

Hopefully you can apply this to your code. If you post some of your code I can help you more.

Comment: That's really interesting Andy! I've managed to create the array and it is populated with my forests forest1,forest2 and forest3. How can directly get the $count from forest2?

Comment: @Sune Hi there, happy new year. I've updated my answer a bit please have a look over it again to see if it answers your question.

Comment: Hi Andy and happy new year:)
Check out my original question. I've added my code.
What I would like to do is ask for the count of FORESTB directly.

Sune:)

Comment: @Sune Thanks for posting your code this helps me see what you are trying to do. There are a number of ways you can get access a property for a specific object in the array. Here is one I would use: `($forestContainer | where {$_.Name -eq "corp.forestb.com"}).Count`. A small recommendation I have is to make the property names a little more descriptive by changing Count to ServerCount.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this. What you're looking to do is create a map/table between the forest and the count for the forest.

Something like

```
Forest  count
======  ======
F1      120
F2      120
```

Three approaches are available

1. Use numerical indexing
2. Use a HashTable for named indexing
3. Use dynamic properties for named indexing

Let's look at each

#### 1. Use numerical indexing

```
$fList = @() #initialize an empty array
$fList += $count # add a new entry
$fList += $count # add another entry
$fList # show all values
$fList[0] # get the 1st value
$fList[1] = 30 # change the 2nd value
```

numerical indexing is great if you know the order of values in the table.

#### 2. Use a HashTable for named indexing

```
$fHT = @{} # hold counts of each forest
$forest = "example"
$count = 100
$fHT.$forest = $count
$fHT # show all
$fHT.$forest # show the count for the current value of $forest
```

#### 3. Use dynamic properties for named indexing

```
$fDP = new-object PSObject
$fDP | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name $forest -value $count
```

and as Andy suggests, these can even be combined

```
$fHT = @{} # hold counts of each forest
$forest = "example forest 1"
$count = 100
$fHT.$forest = $count
$fDP = New-Object PSObject -Property $fHT
$fDP # show all
$fDP.$forest # show the count for the current value of $forest
```

Comment: While `Add-Member` works, the code necessary when adding more than a couple properties can get pretty ugly. Check out Jeffrey's post about the improved way [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/12/05/new-object-psobject-property-hashtable.aspx) :-)

Comment: In the hashtable approach, shouldn't `$forest.$forest = $count` be `$forests.$forest = $count`?

Comment: Thank you Scott! But how would I call the value if i use the NoteMember approach?

Comment: But what if I want the $count from my second forest? $forests.$forest would be  totally dynamic, wouldn't it?

Comment: Not sure what `totally dynamic` means, but I've updated the answer to address how to get the second forest